# Algorithms for down sampling an image?

Tags: texture

Bicubic sampling is pretty good for up sampling an image and making it larger,  but is it a good choice for down sampling as well? Are there better choices?

Comment: These two old articles from *The Inner Product* talk about filters for mipmap generation, which might be relevant to you: [Link1](http://number-none.com/product/Mipmapping,%20Part%201/index.html), [link2](http://number-none.com/product/Mipmapping,%20Part%202/index.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When Sean and I wrote [stb_image_resize](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image_resize.h) we chose Mitchell for downsizing. Mitchell is similar to Cubic, you can read about the cubic class of sampling filters in [Mitchell Netravali 1988](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~fussell/courses/cs384g-fall2013/lectures/mitchell/Mitchell.pdf). They are all pretty similar and will get you very similar results.

I can't find any written record between Sean and I of why we decided to go with Mitchell, but if memory serves we just resampled a bunch of images and used the algorithm that we thought looked best. I wouldn't say that there is one authoritative or best filter, you should use the one that looks best on your data.

Edit: Like joojaa says, a windowed sinc filter is also good, if not quite as cheap. You can find some implementations [here](https://code.google.com/p/imageresampler/source/browse/trunk/resampler.cpp#266).

Comment: There is a authoritatively best filter, its a infinitely wide sinc filter. Its just not possible to use it. untill that time lanczos windowed sinc is a good alternative to michell

Comment: For reference, there's also the [Nvidia image tools](https://code.google.com/p/nvidia-texture-tools/).

Comment: If you are using a cubic-esque or lanczos filter, do those guys work equally well for scaling up as they do for scaling down?

Comment: I've not tried lanczos so I can't speak to that. We chose catmull-rom for upscaling, which is a cubic, and it worked well.